# Code not getting expected values when reading URL parameters

Tags: javascript, url, parameters

I've been racking my brain about this and I can not figure out why this isn't working.

I have a link that looks like this:

```
http://exampledomain.com/page.html?var1=42&var2=hello
```

and page.html is calling a javascript page that says:

```
alert(var1);
alert(var2);
```

But when I test the page all I get is `function Number() { [native code] }`

Anybody know what I could be going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get query string values in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: You're passing `GET` parameters. Javascript doesn't "see" `GET` parameters, it can however read `window.location` and parse it.

Comment: query string value can not retried directly. either u did not post complete question

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/86860

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
var GET = function(query){
    var varsArray = [],
    url = window.location.search.match(/[^\?\&]+/g),
    vars = [];
    for(var i=0;i<url.length;i++)
        if(/\=/.test(url[i]))
            vars.push(url[i]);
    for(var i=0;i<url.length;i++){
        var This = url[i].split('=');
        varsArray[This[0]] = This[1];
    }
    return query ? varsArray[query] : (varsArray || '');
}
```

Comment: I added this to my javascript and it still didn't work. Could I be doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe, because here it worked perfectly. Are you trying to get the GET vars of the current page's url or of a link?

Comment: Usage example: `alert(GET('var1'));` or `var myvar = GET('var2');`